# Scrolling is not smooth when I add a CustomView (Segment bar) dynamically to recyclerView having ScrollView parent

Tags: java, android, android-custom-view, android-scrollview

I have created the `customView` to show the segment bar. Whenever I add the view dynamically with or without `recyclerview` under the parent `scrollView`, the overall `scrollView` stats getting jerky.

Please tell me how to make sure that the `scrollview` will remain smooth whenever I add a custom view. I have tried all solutions like adding an `onMeasure` method to the view as well as tried `nestedscrollview`/`scrollview` etc.

```
CustomView 
public class AvomaSegmentedProgressBar extends View {

    private static final String TAG = "SegmentedProgressBar";
    RectF bgRect;
    private Paint progressBarBackgroundPaint = new Paint();
    private Paint progressBarPaint = new Paint();
 
    public AvomaSegmentedProgressBar(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(null);
    }

    private void init(AttributeSet attrs) {

        dividerPositions = new ArrayList<>();
        cornerRadius = 0;

        TypedArray typedArray = getContext().getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.SegmentedProgressBar, 0, 0);

        try {
            dividerPaint.setColor(typedArray.getColor(R.styleable.SegmentedProgressBar_dividerColor,
                    ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.white)));
            progressBarBackgroundPaint.setColor(typedArray.getColor(R.styleable.SegmentedProgressBar_progressBarBackgroundColor,
                    ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.grey_light)));
            progressBarPaint.setColor(typedArray.getColor(R.styleable.SegmentedProgressBar_progressBarColor,
                    ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.progress_bar)));
            dividerWidth = typedArray.getDimension(R.styleable.SegmentedProgressBar_dividerWidth, dividerWidth);
            isDividerEnabled = typedArray.getBoolean(R.styleable.SegmentedProgressBar_isDividerEnabled, true);
            divisions = typedArray.getInteger(R.styleable.SegmentedProgressBar_divisions, divisions);
            cornerRadius = typedArray.getDimension(R.styleable.SegmentedProgressBar_cornerRadius, 2f);

        } finally {
            typedArray.recycle();
        }

        ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = getViewTreeObserver();
        if (viewTreeObserver.isAlive()) {
            viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    if (getWidth() > 0) {
                        getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                        progressBarWidth = getWidth();
                        dividerPositions.clear();
                        if (divisions > 1) {
                            for (int i = 1; i < divisions; i++) {
                                dividerPositions.add(((float) (progressBarWidth * i) / divisions));
                            }
                        }
                        bgRect = new RectF(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
                        updateProgress();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    /**
     * Updates the progress bar based on manually passed percent value.
     */
    private void updateProgress() {
        invalidate();
    }

    public AvomaSegmentedProgressBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(attrs);
    }

    public AvomaSegmentedProgressBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(attrs);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public AvomaSegmentedProgressBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        init(attrs);
    }



    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);


    }


    private int measureDimension(int desiredSize, int measureSpec) {
        int result;
        int specMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpec);
        int specSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpec);

        if (specMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
            result = specSize;
        } else {
            result = desiredSize;
            if (specMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
                result = Math.min(result, specSize);
            }
        }

        if (result < desiredSize){
            Log.e("SegmentBar", "The view is too small, the content might get cut");
        }
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        if (bgRect != null) {

            canvas.drawRoundRect(bgRect, cornerRadius, cornerRadius, progressBarBackgroundPaint);

            for (Integer enabledDivision : enabledDivisions) {
                if (enabledDivision < divisions) {
                    float left = 0;
                    if (enabledDivision != 0) {
                        left = dividerPositions.get(enabledDivision - 1) + dividerWidth;
                    }
                    float right = enabledDivision >= dividerPositions.size() ? progressBarWidth : dividerPositions.get(enabledDivision);

                    RectF rect = new RectF(left, 0, right, getHeight());
                    canvas.drawRoundRect(rect, cornerRadius, cornerRadius, progressBarPaint);
                    if (enabledDivision == 0) {
                        canvas.drawRect(left + cornerRadius, 0, right, getHeight(), progressBarPaint);
                    } else if (enabledDivision == divisions - 1) {
                        canvas.drawRect(left, 0, right - cornerRadius, getHeight(), progressBarPaint);
                    } else {
                        canvas.drawRect(rect, progressBarPaint);
                    }
                }

                if (divisions > 1 && isDividerEnabled) {
                    for (int i = 1; i < divisions; i++) {
                        float leftPosition = dividerPositions.get(i - 1);
                        canvas.drawRect(leftPosition, 0, leftPosition + dividerWidth, getHeight(), dividerPaint);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Set the color for the progress bar background
     *
     * @param color
     */
    public void setBackgroundColor(int color) {
        progressBarBackgroundPaint.setColor(color);
    }

    public void reset() {
        dividerPositions.clear();
        percentCompleted = 0;
        updateProgress();
    }

    /**
     * Set the color for the progress bar
     *
     * @param color
     */
    public void setProgressBarColor(int color) {
        progressBarPaint.setColor(color);
    }

    /**
     * Set the color for the divider bar
     *
     * @param color
     */
    public void setDividerColor(int color) {
        dividerPaint.setColor(color);
    }

    /**
     * set the width of the divider
     *
     * @param width
     */
    public void setDividerWidth(float width) {
        if (width < 0) {
            Log.w(TAG, "setDividerWidth: Divider width can not be negative");
            return;
        }
        dividerWidth = width;
    }

    /**
     * Set whether the dividers are enabled or not.
     *
     * @param value true or false
     */
    public void setDividerEnabled(boolean value) {
        isDividerEnabled = value;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the number of divisions in the ProgressBar.
     *
     * @param divisions number of divisions
     */
    public void setDivisions(int divisions) {
        if (divisions < 1) {
            Log.w(TAG, "setDivisions: Number of Divisions cannot be less than 1");
            return;
        }
        this.divisions = divisions;
        dividerPositions.clear();
        if (divisions > 1) {
            for (int i = 1; i < divisions; i++) {
                dividerPositions.add(((float) (progressBarWidth * i) / divisions));
            }
        }
        updateProgress();
    }

    public void setProgress(int divisions) {
        if (divisions < 1) {
            Log.w(TAG, "setDivisions: Number of Divisions cannot be less than 1");
            return;
        }
        this.divisions = divisions;
        dividerPositions.clear();
        if (divisions > 1) {
            for (int i = 1; i < divisions; i++) {
                dividerPositions.add(((float) (progressBarWidth * i) / divisions));
            }
        }
        updateProgress();
    }

 
 
}
`

Activity XML

    `enter c<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollViewMeetingDetails"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    >


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_parent_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <!-- Other UI elements according to need-->

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_exoplayer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/frame_layout_main"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="visible">

                <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
                    android:id="@+id/player_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    app:controller_layout_id="@layout/online_player_custom_control"
                    app:hide_on_touch="true"
                    app:keep_content_on_player_reset="false"
                    app:resize_mode="fill" />

                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/loading_exoplayer"
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:visibility="visible" />
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_middleLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/ll_exoplayer"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:background="#EEEEEE" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                android:weightSum="1">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvMeetingHeadig"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/ll_download_control"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:maxLines="2"
                    android:text="EOW Med you accomplished dfgfddfg"
                    android:textColor="@color/cardview_dark_background"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_title"
                    android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>

                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/download_bar"
                    android:layout_width="17dp"
                    android:layout_height="17dp"
                    android:layout_below="@id/tvMeetingHeadig"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:indeterminate="true"
                    android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/custom_rotate_progress"
                    android:visibility="visible" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvPercent"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/tvMeetingHeadig"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/download_bar"
                    android:text="Downloading .. 0%  "
                    android:visibility="visible"></TextView>


                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/ll_download_control"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="3dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imv_download"
                        android:layout_width="17dp"
                        android:layout_height="17dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                        android:clickable="false"
                        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
                        android:paddingTop="0dp"
                        android:paddingRight="0dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/imv_download"></ImageView>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvdownload"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/imv_download"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:text="Download"
                        android:textColor="#868E96"
                        android:textSize="13sp"
                        android:textStyle="normal"
                        android:visibility="visible"></TextView>
                </LinearLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:background="#EEEEEE" />

            <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                android:id="@+id/chipMeetingType"
                style="@style/Chip"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="No Purpose "
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="#868E96"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:chipCornerRadius="3dp"></com.google.android.material.chip.Chip>

            <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                android:id="@+id/chipMeetingOutcome"
                style="@style/Chip"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text=" No outcome  "
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="#868E96"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:chipCornerRadius="5dp"></com.google.android.material.chip.Chip>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:background="#EEEEEE" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal">


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imfb"
                    android:layout_width="18dp"
                    android:layout_height="18dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tvpubDate"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_meeting_regular"></ImageView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvDurationTime"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:padding="2dp"
                    android:text="2 hours 50 min"
                    android:textColor="#868E96"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_subtitle"></TextView>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"

                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imv_host"
                    android:layout_width="18dp"
                    android:layout_height="18dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/no_avatar" />

             

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp">

                    <ExpandableListView
                        android:id="@+id/lst_expandable"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
                        android:childDivider="#00000000"
                        android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
                        android:divider="#00000000"
                        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
                        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
                        android:pointerIcon="cell"
                        android:scrollbars="none" />

                </RelativeLayout>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                </FrameLayout>
            </LinearLayout>


            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:background="#EEEEEE" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:visibility="invisible">

                <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                    android:id="@+id/chip1"
                    style="@style/ThinnerChip"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="32dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                    android:backgroundTint="#0070D2"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                    android:text=" Intro  "
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:chipCornerRadius="5dp" />

                <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                    android:id="@+id/chip2B"
                    style="@style/ThinnerChip"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="32dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                    android:backgroundTint="#17BEBB"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                    android:text=" demo "
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:chipCornerRadius="5dp" />

                <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                    android:id="@+id/chip6"
                    style="@style/ThinnerChip"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="32dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                    android:backgroundTint="#00A9EB"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                    android:text=" Next Steps "
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:chipCornerRadius="5dp" />

                <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                    android:id="@+id/chip3"
                    style="@style/ThinnerChip"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="32dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                    android:backgroundTint="#9013FE"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                    android:text=" Pricings"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:chipCornerRadius="5dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_view_speaker_seg"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"

                />

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: You will have to come up with a minimal example that demonstrates the problem. Nobody will want to look at that wad of code.